# ngx-select-dropdown change style of place holder default value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ngx-select-dropdown

I am using ngx-select-dropdown for angular project. my config is

```
{ 'search': true, 'placeholder': "Select", "searchPlaceholder": "search", 'noResultsFound': 'No results found!', 'clearOnSelection': true, 'height': '150px' };
```

what i have right now is below

[image]

what i want to achieve is

[image]

i want to change color of default value of placeholder "Select" to gray. instead of default color. for all other value selected should be default color and if user deselects all value and "Select" placeholder comes once again, then it should be back to gray.

How will I be able to achieve it.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo for ngx-select-dropdown: https://manishjanky.github.io/ngx-select-dropdown/

In the photo that I have attached, you can see in the right place what is the class that you should use to apply the color.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRS1d.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but thing you are suggesting is easy to do. it will be red for all the values. I want red only in case select is there in the dropdown which is place holder. which comes if all the values are deselected.